# License of a plugin for a LGPL program

Tags: plugins, lgpl

I would like to create a non-free plugin for evolution which use a LGPL license ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link your commercial code against a LGPL library.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGPL